# Why is my notification event not firing in Cordova?

Tags: ios, cordova, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, amazon-sns

I am publishing a notification from Amazon SNS and receiving it properly on my device.

Here is a sample message I'm sending:

```
{
  "APNS_SANDBOX": "{\"aps\":{\"alert\":{\"title\":\"A short string describing the purpose of the notification\",\"body\":\"The text of the alert message\",\"launch-image\":\"The filename of an image file in the app bundle, with or without the filename extension. The image is used as the launch image when users tap the action button or move the action slider\"},\"badge\":5,\"content-available\":\"1\",\"category\":\"identifier\",\"thread-id\":\"id\",\"sound\":\"default\"},\"notId\":1,\"custom_key1\":\"value1\",\"custom_key2\":\"value2\"}"
}
```

However when I open the notification on my phone, I was expecting the `notification` event to fire and my goal here is to send the user a to a url when the notification is opened with something like: `window.location='data.some_link_to_notification';`
I stripped all of that out and just added an alert to see if it was getting called, but it does not appear to be.  Here is my `index.js` file.

```
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady.bind(this), false);
    },

    onDeviceReady: function() {
      StatusBar.backgroundColorByHexString('#FFFFFF');

      var push = PushNotification.init({
        android: {},
        browser: {},
        ios: {
          alert: "true",
          badge: "true",
          sound: "true"
        },
        windows: {}
      });

      push.on('notification', function (data) {
        alert("notification event");
      });

      push.on('error', function (err) {
        console.log(err)
        alert('Event=error, message=' + err.message)
      });

      push.on('registration', function (data) {
        console.dir(data)
        console.log('registrationId:' + data.registrationId)

       window.localStorage.setItem("regId", data.registrationId);
      });

     cordova.InAppBrowser.open('app_url', '_self');
    }
};

app.initialize();
```

Comment: It turns out calling `cordova.InAppBrowser.open('app_url', '_self')` breaks to link to my `cordova.js` file, so any listeners are now broken.  Is using the InAppBrowser not a common approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said in your comment, your problem is loading a remote url with `cordova.InAppBrowser.open('app_url', '_self');`

When you navigate to a different page (it doesn't matter if it's a remote page or a local page), all the javascript code is lost, so when the notification arrives the notification event is triggered, but there is nothing left listening.

And as it's a remote page you have another problem, nor cordova.js or any of the plugins javascript is online, if you want to make Cordova plugins work from a remote url you have to upload the iOS cordova.js, the plugins folder and a few more files (If you open the Xcode project on platforms/ios/, you'll see a yellow "Stagin" folder with a blue "www" folder inside, you should upload all that code to your server.
Have in mind that the code is iOS only, so if you want to do the same for Android you should use a different url in your server for each one of them. And remove the `cordova.InAppBrowser.open('app_url', '_self');` from the remote version or it will cause an infinite loop.

Also have in mind that Apple doesn't like apps that load external websites and they might reject your app if they notice.

Comment: Thanks for the info, you’ve confirmed a lot up things read over the last 2 days!